# How to create scrolling dots with border in it

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How can I create like this scrolling dots with border

[image: scrolling dots]

```
SmoothPageIndicator(   
    controller: controller,
    count: 3,
    effect:  const  ScaleEffect(
        scale: 1.5,
        dotHeight: 10,
        dotWidth: 10,
        dotColor: Colors.red,
        activeDotColor: Colors.grey,
        activePaintStyle: PaintingStyle.stroke,
        strokeWidth: 2
    ),
    onDotClicked: (index) {
        controller.animateToPage(index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    },
)
```

here is the output:

[image: Output of the my code]

I'm trying to achieve like the first image

Answer (score 0):

That effect works with ScrollingDotsEffect. and set fixedCenter:true.

```
    SmoothPageIndicator(
            controller: _controller,
            count: 4,
            effect: const ScrollingDotsEffect(
                activeDotColor: Colors.pink,
                fixedCenter: true),
          )
```